# In C#, how can I return what a property of an object refers to?

Tags: c#, .net, oop, reference

Let me explain what I mean. Say I have an object

```
public class Foo
{
    public int Val { get; set; }
}
```

and another like

```
public class Bar 
{
     public Foo Reference { get; set; }
}
```

Let's say I have

```
Bar mybar = new Bar() { Reference = new Foo() { Val = 69 } }
```

and I want to ***temporarily*** set

```
mybar.Reference = null;
```

then set it back to what it previously was. Well, I can't do

```
var temp = mybar.Reference;
mybar.Reference = null;
mybar.Reference = temp;
```

because line 2 of the above sets `temp` to `null`. So how can I do what I'm trying to do?

Comment: "because line 2 of the above sets temp to null" - what? - `mybar.Reference = null;` can't change value of `temp`. Please provide [MCVE] that demonstrate behavior you see.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you can do it, and it will work.

Reference types, as your `Foo` is, contains only "reference" to the actual object. So property `Bar.Reference` contain memory address to the actual object of `Foo`.

Your code:

```
var temp = mybar.Reference;
```

Code above will copy "memory address/reference" to variable `temp`.
Now both `temp` and `mybar.Reference` pointing to the same object in the memory.

```
mybar.Reference = null;
```

Code above set variable `mybar.Reference` to `null`, now `mybar.Reference` pointing "nowhere", but notice, that `temp` still have a reference to your original object.

```
mybar.Reference = temp;
```

Last line copy "memory address" from `temp` back to the `mybar.Reference`